# Visual Studio Emulator for Android giving me error

Tags: windows-10, android, visual-studio

trying to run this Android emulator and it's giving me issues. 
My computer model is a Toshiba C855D-S5340

> 0> 12/12/2016 4:41:24 PM : [Informational] ===== Session Started =====
>   1> 12/12/2016 4:41:25 PM : [Informational] Emulator manager version: 1.1.622.2
>   1> 12/12/2016 4:41:25 PM : [Informational] Emulator manager plugin version: 1.1.622.2
>   1> 12/12/2016 4:41:25 PM : [Informational] Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0 Windows 10 Pro
>   1> 12/12/2016 4:41:29 PM : [Informational] Virtualization type: UnknownOrNotVirtual
>   1> 12/12/2016 4:41:29 PM : [Informational] Virtualization Version: tosinv - 1
>   1> 12/12/2016 4:41:29 PM : [Informational] Virtualization Serial Number: zc271126q
>   1> 12/12/2016 4:41:29 PM : [Informational] Virtualization Product: portable pc
>   1> 12/12/2016 4:41:29 PM : [Informational] Display Adapter 0: Name: AMD Radeon HD 7310 Graphics, Version: 15.201.1151.0
>   2> 12/12/2016 4:41:31 PM : [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
>   2> 12/12/2016 4:41:32 PM : [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 3 Platforms: 2
>   2> 12/12/2016 4:41:32 PM : [Informational] Reinitializing installable profiles.
>   2> 12/12/2016 4:41:32 PM : [Informational] Installable profiles initialized. Devices: 38 Platforms: 5
>   3> 12/12/2016 4:41:54 PM : [Informational] Waiting to launch device...
>   3> 12/12/2016 4:41:55 PM : [Informational] Launching Device: 7" KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet
>   3> 12/12/2016 4:41:55 PM : [Informational] Validating emulator arguments...
>   3> 12/12/2016 4:41:55 PM : [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running...
>   3> 12/12/2016 4:41:55 PM : [Informational] Preparing virtual machine...
>   3> 12/12/2016 4:44:16 PM : [Critical] An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 7" KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet' device.
>   3> 12/12/2016 4:44:16 PM : [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\xde.exe
>   3> 12/12/2016 4:44:16 PM : [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 7\" KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet" /memSize 1024 /diagonalSize 7 /video "1200x1920" /vhd "C:\Users\Flex Luthor\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\7_KitKat_(4.4)_XHDPI_Tablet\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 7-inch KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet.flex luthor" /noStart /silent
>   3> 12/12/2016 4:44:16 PM : [Critical] XDE Exit Code: HypervisorNotRunning (13)

The log file as provided here [logfile](http://wepaste.com/error/)

Comment: Do you have Hyper-V enabled?

Comment: I believe I do. I set it to auto

Comment: "I believe I do" doesn't answer my question.  The error is directly connected to the VM.

Comment: Could you explain how to enable it?

Comment: Windows Feature